# c# Wrong data in Sokcet programming

Tags: c#, socket.io

I've been developing simple remote desktop program sending, receiving screen images between server, client and doing mouse control, keyboard control.

When I attempted to send server mouse X,Y position to client to control, client received wrong data.

ex) server sends data which is `MouseControl$Position$10(Mouse_X_Position)$10(Mouse_Y_Position)$450(pictureBox.Width)$450(pictureBox.Height)`. It works well at first, client receives the same data that server sent. But, a few seconds later client receives data like `ntrol$Position$10(Mouse_X_Position)$10(Mouse_Y_Position)$450(pictureBox.Width)$450(pictureBox.Height)`. Some part of The first word `MouseControl` is disappeared while server still sends right data `MouseControl$Position$10(Mouse_X_Position)$10(Mouse_Y_Position)$450(pictureBox.Width)$450(pictureBox.Height)`

Help me out of this trouble. I want to know why it is happening
Thank you in advance!

Here is my code below

```
    -server
    private void StartMouseControl()
    {
        NetworkStream MouseControlStream = MouseControlDataSock.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = null;

        while (true)
        {
            Point PointXY = pictureBox1.PointToClient(new Point(Control.MousePosition.X, Control.MousePosition.Y));
            int MouseX = PointXY.X;
            int MouseY = PointXY.Y;

            /* when mouse pointer in pictureBox ... */
            if ((MouseX >= 0 && MouseX <= pictureBox1.Width) && (MouseY >= 0 && MouseY <= pictureBox1.Height))
            {
                MouseControlStream.Flush();
                buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("MouseControl$Postion$" + MouseX.ToString() + "$" + MouseY.ToString() + "$" + pictureBox1.Width.ToString() + "$" + pictureBox1.Height.ToString());
                MouseControlStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                MouseControlStream.Flush();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(400);
        }
    }




    -client
    private void StartMouseControl()
    {
        int BUFFERSIZE = 72;
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];

        while (MouseControlDataSock.Connected)
        {
            /* seperate protocol data from server and save in Sep_message[] */
            MouseControlstream = MouseControlDataSock.GetStream();

            read = 0;
            while (read < buffer.Length)
            {
                int readbyte = MouseControlstream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read);
                if (readbyte == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                read += readbyte;
            }
            MouseControlstream.Flush();

            string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, read);

            string splitter = "$";
            char[] split = splitter.ToArray();

            string[] Sep_message = message.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (Sep_message[0].Equals("MouseControl"))
            {
                if (Sep_message[1].Equals("Postion"))
                {
                    // Mouse_X_Position, Mouse_Y_Position, pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height
                    int MouseX_FromServer = int.Parse(Sep_message[2]);
                    int MouseY_FromServer = int.Parse(Sep_message[3]);
                    int PicBoxWidth_FromServer = int.Parse(Sep_message[4]);
                    int PicBoxHeight_FromServer = int.Parse(Sep_message[5]);
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Pikoh!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming that your data *arrives* in the same units in which it is *sent*; that might work with UDP, but with a TCP stream there is no such guarantee - and if you have automatic buffering and/or "nagle" enabled, it certainly isn't going to happen. So: when you have "some data" from the socket, `message` could be (any of):

- exactly one message
- half of one message
- a single character
- one and a bit messages
- the end of one message, 17 entire messages, and the start of another

In the case of unicode, it could also be **parts of a single character** - which is why you should work in binary until you know you have a "frame", and only do unicode decoding inside a frame. So you also need to account for:

- the end of one character, one entire character, and half of another character (zero frames)

It is *your job* to split the TCP stream into "frames" (i.e. logical messages inside a stream). Since this is a text-based protocol, newlines would be the obvious way to track entire messages. It is *also* your job to keep a back-buffer of data that you aren't able to process yet - i.e. incomplete frames; which should (as mentioned) be *binary* unless you know you are only ever going to see ASCII data.

Comment: Thank you,Marc Gravell! As you mentioned, I will make logical messages and send them to server and split, combine for complete frames.